# JQuery show/hide FAQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some problems working with JQuery to show and hide, when a user click on some class element.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="faqSectionFirst">
Question?

<p class="faqTextFirst" style='text-align:justify'>
<span>
Some text.
</span>
</p>
</div>
```

My JS Code is:

```
$('.faqSectionFirst').on("click", function(){

if( $('.faqSectionFirst').index(this) ) {
    $('p.faqTextFirst').show();
} else {
    $('p.faqTextFirst').hide();
}
}
);
```

Anyone can help me? This isnt working.
I have 20 questions, with 20 answers and i would like to make it work for all.

Comment: Do you want this to behave like an accordion (only one open at a time) or can several be open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.faqSectionFirst').on("click", function () {
    $('p.faqTextFirst', this).toggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CFBJ/3/)

Comment: Thats working, thank you! but how do i hide before click, and only show after clicking?

Comment: Add this above (See fiddle-link above): $('.faqSectionFirst p.faqTextFirst').each(function() {$(this).hide();});

Answer (score 2):

Best way to use `<dd><dt>`

#### HTML

```
<dl >
    <dt>Question 1?</dt>
    <dd>Answer of Question 1.</dd>
    <dt>Question 2?</dt>
    <dd>Answer of Question 2.</dd> 
</dl>
```

#### CSS

```
dd { display:none; }
dt { padding:4px; font:bold 13px verdana;cursor:pointer;}
```

#### jQuery

```
$(document).on('click','dt', function() {
    var myDD = $(this).next('dd');
    $('dd').slideUp();
    myDD.slideToggle();
});
```

[`Working Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/BMStn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`JQuery accordian`](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/), if I understand the issue correctly.  The headers could represent the questions, that the expandable panel the answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code:**

```
<div class="faqSectionFirst">
  Question?
 <p class="faqTextFirst" style='text-align:justify'>
  <span>
   Some text.
  </span>
 </p>
</div>
```

**Solution:**

Now if you want to hide the question totally you can use this jquery code:

```
$('.faqSectionFirst').click(function () {
 $(this).toggle();
});
```

`this` will make sure, that only the element on which the event happened will be hidden or shown. And `toggle()` is a method, to hide or show it. You must have specific jQuery version to make them work.

**Read this:**

One more thing. You must have a seperate div, on which once click event happens the question should be shown. Because the code I am providing and the code that would answer your question, will hide the question itself leaving no change to show it again! So make sure this doesn't happen. :)

Good luck buddy, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the shortest approach, but in my experience it will always be the most robust one - because jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` are basically assigning the properties `display: none` and `display: block` (respectively) to the element it's chained to. `toggle()` is like both combined, still supporting only `display: block`. That might give you undesired results if you'd rather have `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block`, for instance.

So my advice is: *always use classes to control `CSS`, not `JavaScript`*. That will ensure you have full control over your style. The following example would work well:

**HTML**

```
<a class="click-trigger" href="#"></a>
<div class="element"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var c = $('.click-trigger');
var e = $('.element');
c.click(function() {
    if (e.hasClass('hidden')) {
        e.removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
    } else {
        e.removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.click-trigger,
.element { height: 20px; width: 20px; }
.click-trigger { background-color: red; display: block; }
.element { background-color: blue; }

.hidden { display: none; }
.shown { display: block; }

/*
display alternatives not supported by jQuery's 'show()' nor 'toggle()':

display: inline;
display: inline-block;
display: list-item;
display: flex;
display: inline-flex;
display: table;
display: inline-table;
display: table-row-group;
display: table-column;
display: table-column-group;
display: table-header-group;
display: table-footer-group;
display: table-row;
display: table-cell;
display: table-caption;
*/
```

In this example the markup was stripped down for the sake of simplification. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamyguy/Q6m3n/).